# Count all amount from object in a List

Tags: java

I have this Java object stored in a List:

```
public class ExpressCheckout
{
    String currency;
    float amount;
    int quantity;
    String name;
    String description;
.......
}
```

How I can count all amount value into List from every Object?

Answer (score 3):

do something like:

```
public float sumAmounts(List<ExpressCheckout> myList){
  float total = 0.0f;
  for(ExpressCheckout item : myList){
    total += item.getAmount();
  }
  return total;
}
```

just put them inside a `for` or a `foreach` and sum amounts

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8 a very simple technique with streams is:

```
list.stream().mapToDouble(ExpressCheckout::getAmount).sum();
```

Comment: I need the total value in Float. I change it to list.stream().mapToFloat(ExpressCheckout::getAmount).sum(); but I get   non-static method getAmount() cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 0):

Caveat , I use Java 8 and logically assuming when you have multi currency you cannot simply sum them all. You may need to group by currency and sum. This gives you a fair idea on that

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class SomeClass {
    protected class ExpressCheckout {
        public String getCurrency() {
            return currency;
        }

        public void setCurrency(String currency) {
            this.currency = currency;
        }

        public float getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }

        public void setAmount(float amount) {
            this.amount = amount;
        }

        public int getQuantity() {
            return quantity;
        }

        public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        String currency;
        float amount;
        int quantity;
        String name;
        String description;

        public ExpressCheckout(String currency, float amount, int quantity, String name, String description) {
            this.currency = currency;
            this.amount = amount;
            this.quantity = quantity;
            this.name = name;
            this.description = description;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ExpressCheckout> expressCheckouts = new ArrayList<ExpressCheckout>();
        ExpressCheckout co1 = new SomeClass().new ExpressCheckout("USD", 20.01f, 2, "Item1", "Some item");
        ExpressCheckout co2 = new SomeClass().new ExpressCheckout("USD", 2.0f, 2, "Item1", "Some item");

        ExpressCheckout co3 = new SomeClass().new ExpressCheckout("INR", 100.01f, 2, "Item1", "Some item");

        ExpressCheckout co4 = new SomeClass().new ExpressCheckout("INR", 100.01f, 2, "Item1", "Some item");

        ExpressCheckout co5 = new SomeClass().new ExpressCheckout("INR", 200.01f, 2, "Item1", "Some item");
        expressCheckouts.add(co1);
        expressCheckouts.add(co2);
        expressCheckouts.add(co3);
        expressCheckouts.add(co4);
        expressCheckouts.add(co5);
        System.out
                .println(expressCheckouts.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SomeClass.ExpressCheckout::getCurrency,
                        Collectors.summingDouble(SomeClass.ExpressCheckout::getAmount))));

    }

}
```